# how do I read multiple variables from a sub shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, subshell

I've found similar problems on stackexchange, but never close enough to my case to help.

I'm trying to create a script and bind it to a key, so that when pressed, it displays "`title` by `artist`" OR, if there is no artist/title, it displays "`filename`".

Cmus (my music player of choice) has `cmus-remote` paired with the `-C` (raw) option which let me query cmus player for anything and get a newline-separated response like:

```
cmus-remote -C 'format_print %a %t %F'
Beach House
Space Song
/home/user/Music/Beach House - Space Song.mp3
```

The thing is, I don't want to run `cmus-remote` for each of the queries and instead would prefer

```
IFS= read -r artist title file << EOF
$(cmus-remote -C 'format_print %a %t %F')
EOF
```

However that only provides `artist` and `title` and `file` are empty
Note: removing the `-r` option doesn't help in this case, nor does modifying `IFS`.

To elaborate: my Music folder isn't fully tagged, i.e. some songs don't have an artist or title, so the idea of this script is on exec to send a notification 'playing `title` by `artist`', if there's no title or artist 'playing `filename`' so I kindof need to have the three variables to then evaluate wich notification to send.

Comment: while yes, I do indeed use bash, i would prefer to have something more portable, though I will use bash if that's the more practical thing to do

Comment: oops I completely misunderstood the task

Comment: Oh, oh, oh, sorry! Was that an answer? I thought you were just clarifying what you need. Answering your own question is not frowned upon _at all_. It is actually actively encouraged. This still doesn't make the variables survive after the `while` finishes, is that really all you need? If so, please let me know and I will udnelete your answer with my apologies.

Comment: @terdon I believe that was an answer. I have undeleted.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry, @Dr.Coomer, my bad! I now rolled back my edit since it was I, not you, who was being dumb!

Comment: Thanks folks! while I suppose having variables survive outside the loop might be nice, I don't exactly need it, a simple `if a and t else f` inside the loop is just fine for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I just need a read for every newline, i.e.

```
cmus-remote -C 'format_print %a %t %F' | 
while IFS= read -r artist; IFS= read -r title; IFS= read -r file
do
  echo "a:$artist"
  echo "t:$title"
  echo "f:$file"
done
```

runs once and echoes the correct value, why `IFS=$'\n'` doesn't act like you'd think is beyond me, I'll accept three reads